# AWS SQS add-permission deny access

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, command-line-interface, amazon-sqs

Reading and using this

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/add-permission.html ,

but I can't see a way to add a 'deny' rule for a user+action combination, it is adding an 'allow' rule by default, and I can't seem to modify it.

Through the web management console, you can easily add 'deny' rules.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: It looks as if the actual answer is the CLI tool simply offers limited functionality when it comes to permissions unless you want to write your own policy document, but the first part of my answer was incorrect:

<strike>As I understand it, SQS *permissions* don't "deny" -- they only "allow", but the "allow" can be subject to *[conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition)* you can add in the console or via the API to associate other "but only if" tests with the permission such as date ranges and IP address ranges.</strike>

It looks like the design of the CLI is such that conditions [add: and policies with "Effect = Deny"] aren't handled by `add-permission`, which only supports simple grants... to attach conditions, you have to generate a policy document, which you can attach with `set-queue-attributes`.

> `add-permission` writes an SQS-generated policy. If you want to write your own policy, use `set-queue-attributes` to upload your policy.

Comment: Permissions do support 'deny', but only through the [web console](http://cl.ly/image/2R0L0A0h1e0l). But yeah, it looks like I have to create a policy that I need to attach. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what I should have realized; this was a case where my assumptions of how things worked actually kept me from even noticing the very obvious o Allow o Deny radio buttons on the dialog.  I've updated the answer to reflect more accurate information, and put "AWS Permissions and Policies" on my list of books to write.